# Why does 30/9/2013 not fail IsDate() if system date format set for mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: excel, vba, date

I'm trying to write some VBA in Excel 2016 to validate entered dates in one column.  I'm using a simple:

```
If Not IsDate(SourceSheet.Cells(r, c)) Then ...
```

If the value in the cell is 53/9/2013, the IsDate() function will return False, but if the value is 30/9/2013, the IsDate() function returns True, which should be wrong for dates in mm/dd/yyyy format.  I'm in the USA and my Windows system date formats are set to mm/dd/yyyy.

How can I force Excel to treat 30/9/2013 as an invalid date?

Comment: IsDate() checks for almost any valid date and it's not culture specific, at least that's how I understand it. I'm walking out the door so I won't be back until tomorrow, but hopefully this link gets you to the goal line https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Seems like `IsDate()` is very forgiving: http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/understanding-the-excel-vba-isdate-function/

Comment: If these are *user-entered* dates then the cell format will remain at "General" (assuming it was not previously set to some other format) if the date can't be parsed according to the local mm/dd vs dd/mm setting.  None of this helps though if the user enters (eg) Sept 12 as `12/9/2013`

Comment: Just a thought - does isdate convert the date (in whatever format) to the date code?

Answer (score 1):

As Tim Williams pointed out "IsDate() is very forgiving"  If it kind of looks like a date, *IsDate()* will return TRUE.

You and I can examine a cell that looks like a date and determine if is real or just text by touching <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> *(that is Ctrl-tilda)*.

If it is a real date constant, the underlying numerical value will be displayed.

To prod VBA into making a similar test:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim b1 As Boolean, b2 As Boolean, r As Range
    Set r = ActiveCell
    b1 = IsDate(r.Value2)
    b2 = IsDate(r.Value)
    If b2 Then
        If Not b1 Then
            MsgBox "true date"
        Else
            MsgBox "fake date"
         End If
    Else
        MsgBox "not even close"
    End If

End Sub
```

This should be valid for constants..............not sure for formulas.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, where `r` is a worksheet cell

```
Function isRealDate(r As Range) As Boolean
    isRealDate = IsDate(r.Value) And IsNumeric(r.Value2)
End Function
```